# What does the wavevector $\textbf{k}$ mean?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, wavefunction, crystals

In Ashcroft, Mermin Solid State Physics, Eq. 17.43 is

$$
\epsilon(\textbf{k}) = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} - e\phi(\textbf{r})
$$

where $\textbf{k}$ is the [wavevector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector) and all other symbols have their usual meaning.

What does the wavevector tell me and why do we use it instead of position $\textbf{r}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $\vec{r}$ is actually a position vector it points out a particles particular position with reference to some origin, the wave vector $\vec{k}$ actually tells us more as it is related to momentum $\vec{p}$ which gives us a sense of direction of travel of the wave.

Comment: Imagine a plane wave, $\vec{r}$ will point from the origin to a spot on the plane wave not necessarily in the direction of travel, whereas the wave vector points from the wave front outwards.

Comment: Why is it useful to know that?
@Dan: What can you use the direction of the travel of the wave for?

Comment: Well it is useful to know in case of reflection and transmission problems when faced with differing interfaces. Knowing the incoming direction lets you decompose the wave into components and solve for the resulting transmission and reflection coefficients.

Comment: We can also then solve various problems using this wave solution like the transfer of energy of a wave via the poynting vector which requires knowledge of the direction of the electric field waves (the magnetic field is related to the direction of the electric field by $\vec{B} = \frac{1}{c} \hat{k} \times \vec{E} $)

Comment: I'm coming from a chemistry background, so I think in terms of discrete eigenfunctions. But I know in solids, the eigenfunctions start form continuous bands. Is it fair to say that $\textbf{k}$ is actually what points out an eigenfunction in a band?

Comment: In chemistry, and related physical chemistry, the wave vector, or number, is brought up similarly to how it is done in quantum mechanics. We are given a specific potential and we attempt to solve the Schroedinger wave equation for the wave functions of the particle (related to the probability that the particle be in any specific place usually by $| \Psi(x)|^2$) when solving for simple problems we find that (like the particle in a box) that k is related to the energy of a given state $E_n$ where n is the number of the given state..

Comment: Since energy is related to the eigenfunctions it is vary similar to what you mentioned about k specifying the eigenfunctions. Differing eigenfunctions correspond to differing k values.

Comment: I might add here is also a pdf on electronic band structure I found https://www.phas.ubc.ca/~berciu/TEACHING/PHYS315/LECTURES/FILES/band_structures.pdf, and this which helps out on k though be careful its designed more for the layperson http://skepticsplay.blogspot.com/2011/06/what-is-electronic-band-structure.html

Comment: I actually think the blog post is helpful. Einstein said, if you can't explain something in simple terms, you probably didn't understand it... From reading the blogpost, I wonder how is $\textbf{k}$ related to the velocity? $\textbf{p} = m\textbf{v} = \hbar \textbf{k}$, and so $\textbf{v} = \hbar/m \textbf{k}$, if i remember right. But anyway, the most important point for me is to know now that $\textbf{k}$ identifies an eigenfunction.

Comment: k determines the energy eigenvalue, the energy eigenvalue determines a particular eigenstate of the electron yes

Comment: I could accept your answer if you could summarize the last part of our discussion in it.

Comment: Yes summarized the k value determines eigenfuctions directly through the energy eigenvalues

Comment: This answer is wrong. Ashcroft and Mermin have a section explaining that $\hbar \vec{k}$ is not the electron's momentum.